# Is it possible to see own 'review queue audits' results?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I completed recently a few review audits, some of them I passed, some I failed.

Is there a place I could (easily) find these results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see *all* your review actions in your [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852866/strah?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (sorted by reviews). Audits are not specifically marked in this list however.

You'll need to look at your reviews one-by-one to find which ones are audits. I don't think there are plans to make the audits easier to find.

However, I had no problems finding at least a few audits that were presented to you:

- [Suggested edit audit, Passed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1601980)
- [Suggested edit audit, Passed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1601820)

Comment: Thank you. I know I can click through every review in the history. I was just wondering if there is an easier way to access/filter audits.

Comment: There isn't any. I suspect that that is intentional and not going to change.