# Moderators should have easy access to a user's complete review history, including audits

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, review-audits

We often get questions here on Meta or through other channels about why a particular user was banned from review by the system. Additionally, we frequently want to look into a user's review history when we see approved spam or other bad reviews in order to see if there's a larger problem with this user.

However, it's not all that easy for moderators to get a comprehensive view of a user's review history right now. We can look in their recent review activity within their profile, but that hides reviews on deleted posts (like spam or non-answers) and some types of audits. Failed audits aren't identified or listed anywhere. Moderators do get access to more detailed statistics on review, and can eventually look at each user's reviews within a given queue, but this is a laborious process. I usually have to construct a URL by hand to look at a particular user's reviews.

It would be really helpful for moderators to have quick access from a user's profile to a list of all of their recent reviews (including deleted posts), in the style of what we get from the review statistics view. Additionally, a list of audits with pass / fail status ([possibly even having this available to users for them to learn from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169159/is-it-possible-to-see-own-review-queue-audits-results)) would save a tremendous amount of time when researching this for a given user, instead of having to click through every single review to see if it was an audit.

Comment: I do agree that this part of the system could use some developer love.