# Tell moderators more about reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools

Please can we moderators get some more details about what people did whilst reviewing, on the review outcome page itself.

It's fairly common to look into some reviews a bit deeper (e.g. "how on earth did this post survive a review?") which then leads to further questions.

With the current tools it's quite hard to find out exactly what the user saw and what actions they took on a question. The least helpful of all is when we just see the word "reviewed". We then have to hunt through edit history, guess about votes, comments (and deleted comments), flag history, comment votes, comment flags and probably more to figure out what they actually did.

This is in stark contrast to the information we get with flags, which include a textual description of all the activity undertaken by all the flag casters.

This feature request is effectively the inverse of [Brad's request for more user review info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199218/153020), in that I'd like to see more on the review outcome page (in addition to the user profile obviously, but that's already been requested).

Note that I'm only requesting that this information be available to ♦-moderators; I realize this information is too sensitive to make available to all users.

Comment: It's the voting thing... I'd love this for ordinary users as well, and it could be added apart from the fact you wouldn't be able to obfuscate voting enough, and it's meant to be secret...

Comment: I understood the point about moderators @D.W (it's in the title). However, _no one_ has access to voting information, not even moderators so I still don't see how this will be possible without giving them that information.

Comment: Do you mean something like an improvement on `/admin/review/breakdown` or something entirely different?

Comment: @Ame sort of, but on specific review outcome pages rather than in aggregate.