# Incorrect/Misleading Defending the Unicorn Quiz Stipulations

Tags: discussion, bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

In the attempt to save Sparkles there is a quiz. One of the stipulations is as follows:

> All answers are either integers or at most two words (***no punctuation***,
> spaces optional), case insensitive

I've emphasized the portion I found to be incorrect/misleading. One of the answers certainly contained a punctuation character. I tried it without the character, as a space and without, and only the answer with the punctuation was accepted.

Comment: I believe I know what you're talking about, one question needed a  -  in the answer to be accepted.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the same answer that RedzGoose is talking about, this was probably partly my fault – see [my comment on this answer to the 2022 Sparkles MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385137/lets-check-in-on-sparkles-the-unicorn?rq=1#comment1285678_385501) for an explanation.

Comment: @V2Blast I am certain we're discussing the same QnA here. It was pretty isolated and I didn't run into any other issues with answers and punctuation.