# Reviewing "timeout" period for audit failure

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I have searched high and low but have been unable to find an explanation of why the timeout period for audit failures gets longer and longer.

I fully understand and support the use of the audits and, as a new reviewer, use them to learn from my mistakes but making a timeout period last more than a month seems a bit excessive.

I believe that I have made a good faith effort to be very careful and thoughtful when reviewing things but the process is really very subjective in spite of the efforts to make it more objective.

I have read discussions that indicate that the length of time taken on a review is tracked which leads me to ask whether or not that time period is also considered when assigning a reviewing ban.

Comment: More than a month doesn't happen (except for severe abuse, but those are handled by moderators and not by audits); 30 days is the maximum. (Yes, that's more days than February.)

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days/287296#287296

Comment: Thank you @bluefeet ... very discouraging to say the least.