# Are there manual flag bans?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools, flag-ban

In 2013, flag weight and the infamous hellban was [replaced with a new automated system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/336163).

Review bans [are handed out automatically but can also be issued manually by mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275736/336163). The same situation exists with suggested edit bans - [they can be issued automatically *or* by a mod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221832/336163). On the other hand, a [manual question ban does not exist](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3358/21290).

Is there such a thing as a manual flag ban? The flag ban, right now, only looks at flags handled within the past week, so I can see a manual flag ban as being useful if a user continually raises low quality or abusive flags (not flags on low quality or abusive content, but flags that in and of themselves are low quality or abusive or that demonstrate a pattern that is low quality or abusive, such as repeatedly flagging for moderator attention with gibberish text or targeting Spam flags at a disliked user), relying on the fact that any ban is likely to dissipate within a week or so and that they can then go right back to their old flagging habits. On the other hand, I imagine that a case of this that was sufficiently serious to merit a manual flag ban might also be seen as meriting a general site suspension, leaving a manual flag ban as an unneeded feature.

Does a manual flag ban *currently exist*? I'm not asking whether or not it *should* exist, only whether or not this is currently a thing in moderators' toolboxes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there's no tool to issue manual flag bans.

I *can* decline a bunch of flags to trigger an automatic ban, but that's not really manual.

Comment: Also, we can suspend users, setting their reputation to 1 and effectively flag-banning them.