# Lifting/reducing review suspension ban when gaining edit privilege

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, review-suspension

If someone just gained the [Edit Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (which will give access to the Suggested Edits queue) while they are suspended from reviewing, they are able to see a pending review on a post but still can't review it, neither edit the question until that suggested edit is handled, neither access the suggested edit queue that was just unlocked for them.

[image: visible link to pending edit]

When clicking on `edit`, the suspension message will appear in addition to the suggested edit differences, without the ability to do anything.

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again on...Your review on ... wasn't helpful. Please review the history of the post and consider which action would achieve that outcome more quickly.

**Feature suggestion**

On this specific scenario (more or less some conditions like current suspension duration...), lift the review suspension for that user for all queue reviews or at least for [the Suggested Edits​ queue only](https://stackoverflow.com/review). This can be see as an extra bonus with the privilege that may give users (talking about a relatively small reputation user, ~2000 rep only) a chance to learn and improve their reviews.

Related question : [Review bans should escalate beyond 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I disagree.

Becoming suspended from review *isn't easy*. It shows that the care you're taking to review isn't sufficient. In fact, it's insufficient enough that the system had to temporarily stop you from reviewing, or a moderator determined that you needed to be temporarily stopped from reviewing. Why should gaining more reputation and unlocking a new privilege undo, or even reduce, that suspension?

Gaining reputation and reviewing are two completely different processes, and require two completely different skillsets. One requires subject matter expertise, the other requires knowledge of the site's scope and knowledge of how to moderate content. There are plenty of high-reputation users (>50k reputation) on Stack Overflow who are *permanently* banned from review. We should not conflate reputation and reviewing prowess. The only metric by which we should measure review accuracy is... Review accuracy.

If you feel your review suspension should be lifted early, visit that site's Meta site and ask to be unsuspended. Make sure that you explain that you understand that you reviewed incorrectly, and indicate what the correct choices *should* have been. A moderator who sees that you took the initiative to improve your knowledge of the review queue, instead of simply waiting for the suspension to end, will most certainly unsuspend you from review - provided your track record isn't *super* bad.

Comment: I must admit that you brought good points. I just felt that not enough time/chance are given to users to improve. "Becoming suspended from review isn't easy." 3 mistakes/ 1 month = suspended (duration x2 of previous suspension if it is less than 1 month, 1/2 otherwise right?

Comment: The problem is that, if you're getting a review suspension, you've already messed up a bit in the first place, and should probably take some time to learn how to review a bit more properly. We can't cut users a break just because they got more rep. The consequences of reviewing improperly go beyond having your access to review suspended - Site health takes a hit. Questions/answers that should otherwise be flagged via review go under the radar. We should stop bad review practices *before* that user gets access to the edit queue, not cut them slack once they get there. (1/2)

Comment: If you're review suspended and you reach full edit privileges, **it should be alarming** that you can't use half of those new privileges, and **you should be encouraged to improve** your reviews - Not given another chance. (2/2)