# Review bans could consider reviews and passed audits in addition to time elapsed

Tags: feature-request, review-suspension

Since my previous ban ended I reviewed about 450 items and passed many audits.

Well eventually failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34815853) and banned! Now it's 60 days.

On meta there is a question explaining that is not possible to get review bans longer than 30 days:

> [Review suspension progressive system](https://Review%20suspension%20progressive%20system)

That's what one would think if he only reads the accepted and most upvoted question there. However, that information is outdated and one can be ban for increasingly long times.

Quoting this comment on [Review bans should escalate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days):

> Based on this discussion, if I come out of a ban and sit on my laurels
> without reviewing for 30 days, I'm going to have a higher review rep
> then someone who comes out of a ban and starts reviewing immediately -
> crazy – danday74 Oct 30, 2018 at 8:50

Therefore, I would suggest taking passed audits and review counts in the calculations before putting active human reviewers on hold for a long time. Not sure exactly how, but certainly some people with access to data regarding reviewers and bans should  have enough information to come up with a decent idea.

For example:

- passing 5 or 10 audits and failing one would get a warning instead of a ban.
- passing 10 audits reduces the next ban length.
- after 200 reviews the next ban length is reduced.

Looking forward to hear opinions about this.

Comment: Did you open the entire question to check first? If you don't check in context then you're not reviewing properly. [I don't have any rep on SO so I can't see the timeline for the answer being deleted.] Related: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15043/how-do-we-better-educate-new-reviewers-in-the-review-queues and https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15047/please-be-more-careful-with-audit-tests [which devolved into pointless bickering in comments]