# In Stack Overflow en español, review audits do not show in the activity tab

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, international-sites, spanish-stackoverflow

On October 2018, [review audits were activated in Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3723/83). They have been working well and we all are very happy.

However, I noticed that audit reviews do not show in the activity page of users, while [they are supposed to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169161/209901).

For example, I got a review on October 30:

> https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/122646
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But it does not show in the ['activity tab' on my profile:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> <sub>(it should show between reviews on 26 and 30)</sub>

However, on November 19 I passed an [audit on First Posts (Primera publicación)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/125945) and it does show:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

So, we now have a case of First Post showing but Low Quality not.

<sub>Initially [reported on Meta SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3726/83) but [asked to post it in Meta.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/84778?m=47607878#47607878) also.</sub>

Comment: Well [they do show on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169159/is-it-possible-to-see-own-review-queue-audits-results) so yeah, probably a bug indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard exactly. From my experience in SO, they always show on the profile, only that without any signal about them being a review audit.

Comment: To the close flagger: the team has indicated that *English-language* meta questions about foreign-language sites can be asked here; the per-site meta is reserved for questions in that language.